# Kura OSGi - Console does not view my text

Tags: eclipse, console, osgi, bundle, kura

I´m trying to get an output into my console, but it does not work. I have the following example code:

```
package org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloOsgi {

private static final Logger s_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloOsgi.class);

private static final String APP_ID = "org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi";

protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
    s_logger.info("Bundle " + APP_ID + " has started!");

    //console should view this
    s_logger.debug(APP_ID + ": This is a debug message."); 
}

protected void deactivate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
    s_logger.info("Bundle " + APP_ID + " has stopped!");
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
...
ss
"Framework is launched."

osgi> install file:/Users/myname/eclipseworkspace/org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi
undle id is 1023
osgi> start 1023
1023 ACTIVE org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi_1.0.0.qualifier
osgi> ((HERE SHOULD BE MY TEXT))
```

In addition, let me tell you that to handle with Kura and OSGi is still new to me. But I think the question alone makes that clear enough. :D

Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log output does not go to the OSGi console, it goes to the Kura log file. You should see your output in /var/log/kura.log.

Comment: First: Thanks for quick answer. So what goes to the OSGi console? I want to realize a output as mentioned above. (e.g. "osgi> ((HERE SHOULD BE MY TEXT))")

Comment: @meric Did you try `System.out`?

Comment: yes i tried, "System.out" was not what i want. thx. I had the wrong console open ^^ The Equinox console was needed.